# What is the difference between light and dark blue in Chrome network tab

Tags: javascript, php, sockets, google-chrome, web

I'm experiencing a problem where requests (clicks on internal a hrefs) get stuck in pending state. Then when the page does respond, I see in the network tab the pending task divided to light and dark blue. Like this:

[image]

What does the light blue actually mean? Does this mean it was stuck at the client side for the light-blue time, or might it be that the request was stuck at the server?

Comment: light blue means its in waiting state. dark blue means downloading the actual content.

Comment: It says in the box: "**Waiting** (TTFB)". The TTFB means *Time To First byte*, i.e. the time it takes to get the first byte back from the server.

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen How can I debug if the request has been received by the server and is stuck at Apache/Nginx or is stuck at the client side?

Comment: @Noam Well, in this case the client is waiting for a response. In other words, your server is not responding to the client's request. Why it is not responding I cannot say. What is the script, you are calling, doing?

Comment: So according to the network image the request has definitely left the client and is waiting at the server? It's a PHP web application, I'm trying to move the web server from an on-premise server to AWS, and this only happens on my AWS server. I assume some configuration issue, but wasn't even sure if the request has left the client.